# Documentation Search Bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, search

When you go to any topic on Documentation (for example, [Streams](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/88/streams)), type anything in the search box and hit enter, something bad happens:

[image: problemz]

This only happens if you hit enter (if you just select the topic from popup, everything's fine). I tested it on `Chrome 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit), Windows 7` and `Safari, iOS 9.3`.

I'm guessing this is not what the enter key intended for, so that's why I'm reporting this bug.

Comment: Uh oh… it’s reproducible on Firefox as well.

Comment: Also reproducible on Tor Browser, Windows and Chrome, Linux... Looks like it's unrelated to browsers.

Comment: Yeah, this is server-side, nothing to do with the browser. I'm investigating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the report. I was making tweaks in the area and mistakenly didn't commit some things that I *really* should have. Fix has been pushed to production and all should be well again.